# Android, (newbie) different res imagebuttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made the same image button in 36x36,48x48,72x72 and 96x96 and put them in the drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi directories.

I then created a layout and plonked my image button there.

(I am using Eclipse)

in the top left of the screen you can pick the screen size, so I picked 2.7 inches and then cycled right up till 10.1 inches...and every time my image button size changed.

So my question is, do I need to have a different xml layout file for each screen size?

Thanks!

EDIT XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/background_ass">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/level1" 
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1" 
                android:onClick="button_clicked1"
                android:background="#00000000"  android:layout_width="48dip" android:layout_height="48dip">
            </ImageButton>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the point of those separate folders is that, if you provide the same name for that file, the correct resolution file will be chosen based on the screen size. But make sure that you provide the same name for the image. If you see the button resizing accordingly, then you have done this correctly.

Comment: I think i have: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/683/captureuh.jpg/ but the button still looks strange on each screensize and sometimes too small :(

Comment: By strange, do you mean that it always looks overall too small? If so, the easy fix (and only one I can see) would be to either increase each image size by a constant pixel in each dimension or decrease it. I strongly suggest you leave the decision of which image to use up to the Android OS.

Comment: By strange i mean look at this (NSFW -underwear girl) http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/6/finaldi.jpg/
see how the button keeps changing till its almost useless

Comment: Ah I see what you're talking about. In that case, consider making the mdpi and hdpi images bigger. It seems like the image for ldpi is fine across screens of size 2.7, 3.2 and 3.7in (although it looks a bit awkward on the 2.7in screen).

Comment: ^ If you don't notice a difference from that, please post your relevant XML code because that will be the source of the problem.

Comment: Ok, edited the above to add XML. As for the images bigger, I followed the advise from here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and made it  36x36,48x48,72x72 and 96x96 . What dimensions would you suggest?

Comment: Yes it does appear as though you have done this correctly. I take it you are using ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi. This is a better resource when dealing with picture sizes: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

Comment: Also, try viewing it on your actual device as well if your device is a medium or large device (since this is where you're having problems). You'd be surprised how much the AVDs can screw up size.

Comment: I just have a LG with a 4in screen... have not checked it on that as yet, but was hoping my simple game would look the same in small screens right up till big ones. And I cant afford to buy phones from small to the big size :(

Comment: Yes well I totally understand. I wouldn't expect you to buy many phones. :-P It does seem that you are going about this in the correct manner however, and I'm not sure how else to help you other than to say resize your mdpi and hdpi images and see how that changes their appearance on the larger AVDs.

Comment: Thanks, will do, and will also select your answer. Cheers! (Am off to bed)