# Android Supporting Multiple Screens with fixed width icons

Tags: java, android

This may not be explained the best but here it goes.
I have a window of 2 by 2 square icons. I found a custom layout script that spaces these equally on the screen. These 4 icons consist of a square background with a little image and title. 
At the moment the width and height are defined in dp. But that stretches or shrinks the text. I am assuming I need to use fixed values. I understand that there are 4 generalised screen resolutions.

My question is, for small I would have to set the width and heights to x and y, but when the screen gets bigger due to larger devices I would have to increase x and y to keep some sort of continuity.

Is there a minimum and maximum width and height of screens for each size? How do other people get around these issues.

Sorry if it is a bit broad and sweeping, but I am new to creating dynamic (ish) displays for multiple resolutions.

Any help and advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has actually documented this well. When you load your images in your res folder, you will need to simply put high, medium, and low res versions of your file into the file with the same name (but with hdpi and so forth appended to the name of the file). Android will handle which file to choose based on the screen size. I could go through how to do this, but [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) link covers the details of what I'm talking about in greater detail. Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020379/android-newbie-different-res-imagebuttons/7020459#7020459) question I answered a while back. It has a lot to do with your question.

Comment: thank you for the advice. I sort of understand what to do. For example I understand the theory behind creating icons like
    36x36 for low-density
    48x48 for medium-density
    72x72 for high-density
    96x96 for extra high-density
But how can I be sure that if I make each one bigger that a screen wont be too small

Comment: sorry that is really badly explained. If I create an image 48 by 48 or larger and call that the low density is there any way i can be certain they will not be too large? This is why I was wondering if there were min and max pixels for each type

Comment: You're correct they suggest 36x36, 48x48 and so on, but, in my experience, you really must be the judge. Test it on several small-screened AVDs if that is your concern until you get an acceptable low density image and then increase the other images accordingly.

Comment: Also note that the AVDs often skew what actually happens on a real device. So I would also test it out on your own phone or tablet if you have an Android device.

Comment: Your right, unfortunately I have quite a large screen phone which doesnt help. And the AVD certainly doesnt always help

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry man. Not sure how much more I can help you. Seems like you've got the right idea though.