# Android layouts - button size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

This is my code for the button. Thing is, it's the same size on all devices. It's big on small ones and small on big ones. How do I alter its size relatively? Here's my code.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout1"/>
```

I would like the size to be consistent, depending upon the device's resolution.

**EDIT**
I want the buttons to be square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is to use

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

It manages size for all devices very well.

For square buttons you need to set width/height in the code. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3147157/1436931) will help you.

Comment: The thing is, I'd like the buttons to be square.

Comment: Since he was first, he gets the right answer :P I gave you a vote up!

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the width and height in dp, or density-independent pixels. This unit of measure is designed to produce the same *physical* size on all devices regardless of pixel density, because pixel density varies by device. You can also use either of the following values for `layout_width` and `layout_height`:

- `wrap_content` makes the view large enough to hold its content.
- `match_parent` uses the corresponding dimension (width or height) of its parent view.

Also with any of these you can stil specify padding and margins, a la the typical box model.

Android currently does not support percentage style measurements, like making the width be 60% of the available width. The closest you can get to that is using a `LinearLayout` and specifying `layout_weight` values for its child views.

If you want finer control over the size of a view, you can subclass it and override the `onMeasure` method, which is where you would calculate the size of the view and set its width and height by calling `setMeasuredDimension(w, h)`. Here's an example of someone doing just that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3147157/1207921

Comment: Thank you, Karakuri. I already knew this. What I want is square buttons, is there another way to do it?

Comment: You can subclass the view and do your own measurement calculations. Amending my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using image buttons with different sized images according to screen resolution ([Android, (newbie) different res imagebuttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020379/android-newbie-different-res-imagebuttons)).

If you use LinearLayout with android:weightSum="2.0" and you set all of your image buttons with android:layout_weight="1" you will have their width/height exactly 50% of the LinearLayout according to the LinearLayout orientation.